# table view get turned to horizontal

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, ios5

I need to animate the Table view from top of status bar to center in landscape mode, but table view get automatically turned to horizontally i.e starting from right to left . What am i doing wrong? here is my code

```
- (IBAction)pressToGetTableview:(id)sender
{
tableViewhavingOptions.frame =self.view.frame;
tableViewhavingOptions.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x -   
CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), self.view.center.y );
[self.view.superview addSubview: tableViewhavingOptions];

[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(pushAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
tableViewhavingOptions.center = self.view.center;
self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), self.view.center.y );
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check to see the orientation of the viewcontroller

this can be done by using

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations.. use specified orientations that you want to see in the view

    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

and there is also a way to do this in the project properties.. you can set the orientation in project settings window

hope this will solve the problem..:)